# Is this the right way to store data into mysql database?

Tags: php

Is this will be the right way to store datas into database ??

I use this way:

A) When i want to get number from user-end then i will use:

```
$system = intval($_POST['system']);
```

B) When i want to get string from user-end then i will use:

```
$system = mysql_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['system'])));
```

OR

```
$system = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['system'])));
```

Another question, most of the places `mysql_real_escape_string` with `mysql_escape_string` and i found it to be working.

should i stick to `mysql_escape_string` since its working or should i change it again to `mysql_real_escape_string` ??

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli instead

Comment: Better yet use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and most importantly **[prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ)**

Comment: But in my site mysql_escape_string is working. dont know how but its working. should i stick to it ??

Comment: PDO is so much simpler than any direct sql driver, that it really makes sense to use it. You don't have to deal with any of the issues you have with mysql or i like having to write a wrapper around those functions to get them working the way you want. Especially when you start getting into OO Programming you will really enjoy PDO! :)

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: is this is the right way to store string into database ??

$system = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['system'])));

to prevent SQL Injection and XSS since i dont know making prepared statements well.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is not correct here. You should apply that when you bring the data into the context that needs this kind of escaping - that context is called "HTML", not MySQL.